# Autodesk Maya project changed event (signal)

Tags: pyside, maya, mel, pymel

I am writing a project manager for Maya in PySide. It's purpose is to navigate through projects contents for quick accessibility. So I would like it to rescan newly set project directory automaticaly. As far as I know, there is no event like "Project Changed" in maya ScriptJob command. Any advices would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you settings you project? Through the `setProject` command or using Maya's UI?

Comment: In fact, can you add a bit of code that shows us how you set it?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, as there is not any "Project Changed" event in Maya's `scriptJob` command, you have to somewhat hack this. **The following answer implies modifying Maya's file.** So, if you need to deploy your project manager on multiple computers, you'll also have to deploy modifications made on Maya's files.

There might be an easier solution, but couldn't found out how to do it efficiently using the existing events.

**Note:**

I'm using Maya 2014, so change the path provided according to your actual version.

---

**Solution 1 - PyMel based:**

- Goto `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\Lib\site-packages\pymel\core`
- Open `system.py` in your favorite editor
- Search for the `Workspace` class (`@547` in my `system.py`)
- Edit the `chdir` function (`@621`):

  ```
  @classmethod
  def chdir(self, newdir):
     _OpenMaya.MUserEventMessage.postUserEvent('ProjectChanged')
     return cmds.workspace( dir=newdir )
  ```
- Open a **new** Maya (Maya needs to be restarted so the modifications are effective)
- Run this code in your script editor:

  ```
  import maya.OpenMaya as om
  #Register a new event (IE: Tell maya that this event really exists)
  om.MUserEventMessage.registerUserEvent('ProjectChanged')
  from pymel.all import *

  #This function will be called when the project will be changed
  #Do your real stuff inside
  def myCallbackFunction(data):
      print('Got a ChangedProject event!')

  #Tell Maya to run myCallbackFunction when ProjectCHanged occurs    
  callbackId = om.MUserEventMessage.addUserEventCallback('ProjectChanged', myCallbackFunction)

  #Whange your project directory:
  #   - The ProjectChanged signal will be sent
  #   - Maya will catch it and execute myCallbackFunction
  #   - This will print 'Got a ChangedProject event!'
  workspace.chdir(r"C:\Users\dhasselhoff\Documents\maya\projects\hookedonafeeling")
  ```

  - If you want to remove the callback function when done: `om.MUserEventMessage.removeCallback(callbackId)`

---

**Solution 2 - MEL based:**

- Goto `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\scripts\others`
- Open `setProject.mel` in your favorite editor
- Edit the `setProject` function (`@359`):

  ```
      ...
      // Restore the current directory. The project may have changed, but the cur dir
      // need not
      workspace -dir $oldCurrentDir;
      python("import maya.OpenMaya as om\nom.MUserEventMessage.postUserEvent('ProjectChanged')");
  }
  // Try to set it directly from the name given
  else
  {
      sp_setLocalWorkspaceWithoutPopupDialog $newProject;
      python("import maya.OpenMaya as om\nom.MUserEventMessage.postUserEvent('ProjectChanged')");
  }
  ```
- Open a **new** Maya (Maya needs to be restarted so the modifications are effective)
- Run this code in your script editor:

  ```
  import maya.OpenMaya as om
  #Register a new event (IE: Tell maya that this event really exists)
  om.MUserEventMessage.registerUserEvent('ProjectChanged')

  #This function will be called when the project will be changed
  #Do your real stuff inside
  def myCallbackFunction(data):
      print('Got a ChangedProject event!')

  #Tell Maya to run myCallbackFunction when ProjectCHanged occurs    
  callbackId = om.MUserEventMessage.addUserEventCallback('ProjectChanged', myCallbackFunction)

  #Whange your project directory:
  #   - The ProjectChanged signal will be sent
  #   - Maya will catch it and execute myCallbackFunction
  #   - This will print 'Got a ChangedProject event!'
  mel.eval('setProject("C:\Users\dhasselhoff\Documents\maya\projects\hookedonafeeling");')
  ```

  - If you want to remove the callback function when done: `om.MUserEventMessage.removeCallback(callbackId)`